# Scheduled backup of database-tables with new data each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with around 100 tables and approx 700 megabytes of data, where the existing data is truncated each month and replaced by new data. The table-names and columns are unchanged month-to-month. But I need a backup of the data from Month 1 before the data from Month 2 is loaded into the database.

I need to be able to run queries on single-table level from the backup, as I need to validate specific data-rows in last month's tables.

My original database is in this example called `[Data_Master]` and my backup database is called `[Data_Backup]`

I'm considering making a stored procedure where I:

```
        TRUNCATE TABLE [Data_Backup]
        INSERT INTO [Data_Backup].TestTable (xxx, xxx, xxx,...) 
        SELECT xxx, xxx, xxx... FROM [Data_Master].TestTable
```

In my example, I will do this script 100 times in a stored procedure, which is a big task initially but when it's stored in a procedure, it's manageable. But I was thinking, whether there is a better/faster way, where I can get table copied/backup individually in SQL-server, so they are accessible without further ado. I'm looking for inputs, so all inputs are welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest that you modify your schema to allow discerning different months, rather than wiping the data every month.

Comment: Or backup and restore a copy of the older databases,

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an archive database that loads the previous month's data into similarly named tables prior to truncating all of the tables for the next month.

It might be a good idea to keep the values of the identity field as is (without the identity property), as you would also probably want columns for year and month for sorting purposes.

Then if you ever have to look at something from before the previous month, you would be covered.

At the end of a fiscal year, you save off that archive database with the year in the name, and set it to read-only, with some good indexing and now you can start some data mining for trends.